# How can I style input file textbox?

Tags: html, css, input

How can I style html the input file type using css, and also change the browse button, thanks

Answer (score 9):

### Short Answer

You can't.

### Long Answer

Make your file input invisible using `opacity`, then make a fake `div` that contains a normal text input and a button, position it absolutely so that it covers the real input, then set its z index to be below the real input. Style the elements.

When a user clicks on the text input or the button, they will actually be clicking on the real input that is transparent.

**Working example: [styled file input](http://jsfiddle.net/FpBB8/)**

Comment: This will trigger NoScript's ClearClick feature which warns users when they interact with partially hidden form elements - it makes it look like a malicious action is being done, even though in this case, it's obviously not malicious.

Comment: You're right - it will. It remains a working method of applying style to a file input though.

Answer (score 0):

You can not.

You can use a Flash control (usual caveats apply), or absolutely position your custom control behind the existing one, and set its `opacity` to `0`.

That way, apparent clicks to your custom control will actually click your invisible input `input`.

You can capture the text from the `input`, using JavaScript. Browsers generally limit you to the filename only.

Answer (score -1):

you can't !

you can use flash to simulate a file box.