# Changing style of file browse button

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to replace the file browse button in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108149/what-is-the-best-way-to-replace-the-file-browse-button-in-html)
>   [How to style “input file” with CSS3 / Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226167/how-to-style-input-file-with-css3-javascript)

Is possible to change the style of  `<input type='file' />` ?

If yes , how to change?  chrome shows file name which i have been chosen in file browse input.

How to Hide file name in file browse input?

Comment: This topic is already covered in rather good detail in SO. Please do a search and you'll find your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it cannot be changed.

However there is a trick widely circulated around the web. The idea is to give the `<input type="file"/>` an opacity value of `0.1` and position it on top of an image. For all practical purposes it will be invisible and only the picture will be visible, but it will receive mouse clicks. With some Javascript then you can show the selected file name(s) elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 3):

Asked before:

- [How can I style a file input field in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352467/styling-issues-with-a-file-input-field-in-firefox)
- [Styling an input type="file" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button)
- [How to style "input file" with CSS3 / Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226167/how-to-style-input-file-with-css3-javascript)
- [Styling <input type="file">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532733/styleize-input-type-file)
- [Change cursor type on input type="file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537223/change-cursor-type-on-input-type-file)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984815/jquery-best-way-to-style-a-input-file-tag
- [how can i style input file textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840504/how-can-i-style-input-file-textbox)

If you had search it then it would have given you the best possible answers from StackOverflow itself.
Hope it will work !

Answer (score 0):

You can do with few lines of javascript. Here is the sample demo http://jsfiddle.net/eyjsF/