# CSS design a input field type=file

Tags: php, html, css

I have an input field:

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
```

Now i want to design this field like this:

[image]

How can i do this?

Comment: This is CSS 101. Or, 2 mins. in Photoshop (if not even); *take your pick*.

Comment: Please try to show some effort on your part to recreate this, otherwise you are simply asking other people to do your work for you.

Comment: Here you go [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/). Now go fly my young bird! Make daddy proud.

Comment: Here you go [W3Fools](http://www.w3fools.com/) @dowomenfart

Comment: @JayBlanchard Cool... What's your point?

Comment: Please do not *ever* recommend W3Schools @dowomenfart as their information is typically not up to date and is not a reputable as other sources for learning web development.

Comment: So your telling me styling an input is out of date on w3schools? I'm to look on those sites and compare how to style an input... Let's see if they're different. @JayBlanchard

Comment: @JayBlanchard are you one of those people who listens to anything that they read on the internet? Because just did a comparison on CSStricks and HTMLrock and all style the input the same.

Comment: @dowomenfart please do not be insulting. If styling the inputs are all the same that means all is up to date and that is good. As is said on W3Fools, W3Schools is getting better at keeping up. You will find, not just from me, a disdain for W3Schools on SO. If you continue to reference them others will no doubt will offer the same sort of comment that I did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the html:

```
<span class="filewrap">
    Some funny german words I don't understand
    <input type="file"/>
</span>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
.filewrap{
    position:relative;
    background:#000;
    border:1px solid #cc0000;
    padding:15px 100px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}

input[type="file"]{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

See [**this demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5dmfgzr2/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But i have a problem. If i make the windows smaller the span field will break up and go in the next row. Can i give the span maybe a width of 305px? I tried it with no result.

Comment: @Skeptar, make it a div and do that or [do this](http://jsfiddle.net/5dmfgzr2/3/)

Comment: Thanks! It works with the div.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to place an element on top of the input button and order them so that the upload input is underneath and therefore hidden.

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/144uop6y/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="fileUpload btn btn-primary">
    <span>Upload</span>
    <input type="file" class="upload" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fileUpload {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
}
.fileUpload input.upload {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

Some more useful links:

- [How can I style a file input field in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352467/styling-issues-with-a-file-input-field-in-firefox)
- [Change cursor type on input type="file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537223/change-cursor-type-on-input-type-file)
- [Styling an input type="file" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button)
- [how can i style input file textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840504/how-can-i-style-input-file-textbox)
- [How to style "input file" with CSS3 / Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226167/how-to-style-input-file-with-css3-javascript)
- [Styling <input type="file">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532733/styleize-input-type-file)

Comment: Just posting an answer with links isn't much of an answer. Try to provide these links in the comments of the OP.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Taken on board, I've now added some code and a JSFiddle.  Thanks for the feedback. @DaImTo